# hasPrevious() method in doubly linked lists

Tags: java, iterator

For class I am creating a doubly linked list with an iterator. We have just started this sort of stuff, so my experience with it is only a few weeks old.

When creating a method to check if a doubly linked list in Java has an element in the previous position behind a cursor, is it proper to use the following code?

```
 public boolean hasPrevious() {
    if(cursor.prev != null){return true; }
    return false;
```

I am wondering because my professor told me to rethink that method, but I can't really think of where else to go with it. Is there anything certain he may be looking for pertaining to iterators or doubly linked lists that I'm missing?

edit: Yes, my cursor is part of the iteration. It is supposed to be between two elements in the code.

Comment: What is your `cursor`? Are you iterating?

Comment: My cursor is between two elements in the list, and yes, I'm supposed to be iterating.

Comment: Can `cursor` ever be `null`?

Comment: No, it is not supposed to be. Our assignment I feel was fairly vague, but the closest it should get to being null is pointing to a null in the list. Or so I thought, when I coded my hasPrevious() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method could be simplified:

```
public boolean hasPrevious() {
   return cursor != null && cursor.prev != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he wanted you to simplify it a little bit

```
public boolean hasPrevious() {
   if (cursor != null)
      return curser.prev != null;
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the most simplified way

```
public boolean hasPrevious() {
    return (current.previous != null);
}

public E previous() {
    if (hasPrevious()) {
        E result = current.element;
        current = current.previous;
        return result;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you have mentioned here is right, then answer is yes.

Comment: `Is there anything certain he may be looking for pertaining to iterators or doubly linked lists that I'm missing?`

Comment: Yes what? Not an answer.

Comment: So no answer to "my professor told me to rethink that method, but I can't really think of where else to go with it. Is there anything certain he may be looking for pertaining to iterators or doubly linked lists that I'm missing?"